Can anyone identify the typefaces used in this poster?
I'd particularly like to know which typeface was used for the small caps heading: 'Surf Etiquette.'  I can't quite tell if the same font was also used for the subheads like: 'Right of way'.


"Right of Way" et al. look like Avant Guard or maybe Futura to me..... No clue about the header.

This is all Futura.
The site I used to prepare this doesn't have small capitals, but it's possible to see that the main heading is Futura Extra Bold.
Other text is in Futura Bold; top right is Futura Extra Bold Condensed; the small text at the bottom of the image is Futura Medium Condensed Oblique.


I believe this is the correct answer.  I wish I could accept this answer now.
But, I wanted to stick to fonts already installed on my mac to keep to my limited 'production budget.'
In that case, Avenir Next, Heavy is what I actually went with for text like: "RIGHT OF WAY".

@pnadeau You can accept it. Just click the tick (you might have to do that on your own answer first, to unaccept it).

"Right of Way" might be set in "Avenir Next, Heavy" with a bit looser kerning. "Futura Condensed Extra Bold" seems to be a close match for the smaller text.
I still have no idea what the larger text ("Surf Etiquette") is set in though

Might look at Frutiger then.. same designer as Avenir.

Although this is the 'accepted answer,' I believe Andrew Leach's answer to be the correct answer.
